# Show value if exists within text_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form using form_tag that allows users to input a prediction for a football match, the fixtures are taken from a separate model..What i would like to do is once they have submitted their predictions, the next time they view the same form their predictions are prepopulated against the fixtures whist having the input field as  readonly..

Form looks like so

```
<%= form_tag controller: 'predictions', action: 'create', method: 'post' do %>
         <% @fixture_date.sort.each do |date, fixture| %>
           <ul class="fixture-dates">
             <li><h5><%= date_format(date) %></h5></li>
            </ul>

             <ul class="fixtures">
               <% fixture.each do |fixture|%>
                 <% if current_user.predictions.where(:fixture_id == fixture.id).empty? %>
                <li>
                  <span class="home-team"><%= fixture.home_team %></span> 
                  <span class="score">
                  <%= text_field_tag "predictions[][home_score]" %> 
                  <%= text_field_tag "predictions[][away_score]" %>
                  </span>
                  <span class="away-team"><%= fixture.away_team %></span> 
                </li>
                 <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][home_team]", fixture.home_team %>
                 <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][away_team]", fixture.away_team %>

                 <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_date]", fixture.fixture_date %>
                 <%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_id]", fixture.id %>

                 <% else %>
                 pre populated predictions against fixtures here
               <% end %>

               <% end %><!--if statement -->

              </ul>
         <% end %>
           <%= submit_tag "Submit predictions", :class => "btn btn-success btn-large" %>
      <% end %>
```

I had thought about disabling the text input using

```
 :disabled => true
```

but this just seems to return the input with this text

```
{:disabled => true}
```

So once the user has made their prediction it is these two inputs that i would like prepopulated with their prediction

```
<%= text_field_tag "predictions[][home_score]" %> 
<%= text_field_tag "predictions[][away_score]" %>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please

Thanks

EDIT

I now know why the disabled => true outputs the {}, from the docs it seems as if the disabled option takes the previous statement as its argument/value.. so if i do this

'', :disabled => true

then i get a blank text_field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see a text input with `{:disabled => true}` text because `text_field_tag` accepts three arguments: `name`, `value`, and `options`. If you do not specify `value` explicitly, it supposes `{:disabled => true}` to be it. So change your code to the following:

```
<%= text_field_tag "predictions[][home_score]", nil, :disabled => true %>
```

Comment: thanks, so in place of nil for example i could pass the users prediction if one has been made?

Comment: im trying to access the prediction for the user using current_user.predictions.home_score, :disabled => true  but cant access the score

Comment: @Richlewis how do you define `home_score`? Make sure you can access it in the view.